# Support for IE recording

Tags: smartmeter

SmartMeter saves huge time using the built in test recorder but it has a limitation where user has to use built in chromium browser.

May I know How to record business transaction using alternate browser (IE, Firefox) ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot use Chromium plugin with a different browser. It is dependent on Chrome API. But you can always fallback to JMeter way. The HTTP(S) Test script recorder is still available in SmartMeter. There is also [Smart Proxy Recorder](https://www.smartmeter.io/documentation#toc-smart-proxy-recorder), which extends the capabilities of HTTP(S) Test script recorder, but it still based on recording via proxy.